# "-bash: line 7: dpkg: command not found" said CentOS

Tags: centos, dpkg, centos-5

I'd like to use the command `dpkg` in my PHP script (using `exec`).

I'm running CentOS. Is there a way I can install the command `dpkg` on there?

Step by step guide would be fantastic.

Answer (score 13):

These steps worked for me on CentOS 7:

1. Install epel using the following command: `sudo yum -y install epel-release`
2. Refresh repo by typing the following commad: `sudo yum repolist`
3. Install the dpkg rpm packages: `sudo yum install dpkg-devel dpkg-dev`

For more information: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-redhat-7-x/

Comment: These commands raise the error "nothing provides lzma needed by dpkg-dev-1.18.25-12.el8.noarch" on centos8. However `yum install dpkg` after installing epel-release worked

Answer (score 7):

with centos you should be using [yum](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum), since it is the [package manager of centos](http://centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-software-management-concepts.html).

dpkg is for debian (ubuntu) based distributions.

Comment: so there is now way of installing the dpkg command for use in php?

Comment: Use a OS that supports `dpkg` if you want to use `dpkg`

Comment: the real question is: what do you need `dpkg` for in php??

Answer (score 3):

For those who wanted to know: you can install dpkg.

Qouted from http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-i386/dpkg-1.15.5.6-6.el6.i686.rpm.html

1. Download the latest epel-release rpm from
   http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/
2. Install epel-release rpm:

   rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm
3. Install dpkg rpm package:

   yum install dpkg